# Mapping arrays to object

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to turn this...

```
[{
    "name": "Example Playlist",
    "playlist": ["All", "Listing", "Test"]
},{
    "name": "Another Example Playlist",
    "playlist": ["AA", "eee"]
}]
```

To this?

```
[{
  "name": "Example Playlist",
  "playlist-all": [{"name": "All"}, {"name": "Listing"}, {"name": "Test"}]
},{
  "name": "Another Example Playlist",
  "playlist-all": [{"name": "AA"},{"name": "eee"}]
}]
```

I tried to make it by myself with using dozens of forEach but I am really stuck at this point.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: `I tried to make it by myself with using dozens of forEach`  Please show us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const data = [
  { "name": "Example Playlist", "playlist": ["All", "Listing", "Test"] },
  { "name": "Another Example Playlist", "playlist": ["AA", "eee"] }
];

const res = data.map(({ name, playlist=[] }) =>
  ({
    name,
    'playlist-all': playlist.map( e => ({ name: e }) ) 
  })
);

console.log(res);
```